# is there any any way to override tuleap class file?

Tags: tuleap

I have to override tuleap functionality,is there any way to override tuleap core functionality that won't affect tuleap core functions

Thanks

Comment: Hi, your question is a bit vague. You will need to be a bit more specific about which code you want to modify in order to get a worthwhile answer. In short, Tuleap is open source software which means you are free to modify it at will.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

You should try to do a plugin instead. Overriding core functionalities will obviously affects core functions. You can try to play a bit with inheritance but I definitely don't think this is the way to go.